# iOS customised email

Tags: ios

I am looking for a way to customize an email function in my app without using the standard iOS built-in MessageUI.framework. The reason being:

1) I do not want the recipient address to be reflected to avoid spamming.

2) Also, we are a very small company and are using shared server. Although we have our own email address, if we can hide our email address, we could use a gmail address (with better reliability of deliveries) instead without losing professionalism.

3) I do not want the subject and the recipient address editable

etc.

Is there a way to this?

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Good solution is to create an API in PHP which accepts `emails` and `message` as parameter, and handling sending email from server side only. Its the only good way if you want to make email customised, create an UI with only input of message by user, and then can call the API.